# Jquery how to know if value exists on data attribute or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html div like this.

```
<div id="myDiv" data-numbers="1 4 5 3 9 88 57 "></div>
```

Here on data-numbers attribute of div there are random numbers separated with white space.

Now i want to find a value exists on `data-number` or not using `jQuery`. 
For example 1 should return true, 
 2 should false because 2 is not in data-numbers, 
 4 should return true and 7 should return false.

Please help me on finding its solution. 

**PS. I want to avoid loops.** 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want to avoid loops?

Comment: @KunJ there will be so many divs like this on my code. Loop will reduce the performance and makes bigger code size as well. thanks

Comment: OK.. You got the loop free solution from @Johan. Cheers!

Comment: not really but he gave me an idea to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function checkIfNumberExists($el, number){
    var numbers = $el.data('numbers').split(' ');
    return !!~ numbers.indexOf(number.toString());
}

console.log(checkIfNumberExists($('#myDiv'), 1)); // true
console.log(checkIfNumberExists($('#myDiv'), 2)); // false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/re5434ck/

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
var numbers = $('#myDiv').data('numbers').split(' ');

function contains(number){
    return numbers.indexOf(number.toString()) > -1;
}

alert(contains(1));  //true
alert(contains(2));  //false
alert(contains(7));  //false
alert(contains(57)); //true
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/80/)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT-
This should do it-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var all=$("#myDiv").attr('data-numbers');
console.dir(all);
var mm= all.toString();

var kk= mm.split(' ');

$.each(kk,function(key, val){
if(val == '2'){
console.log('2 is found');
}
})

})
```